# Output multi dimensional array while keeping original key set

Tags: php

I'm not even sure if I am writing this code as efficiently as possible but I'm stuck and need help...

HTML

```
<?php
    echo outputDirArray($dir_array, 0, '');
?>
```

In PHP, I have a function to put my directories into an array:

```
function dirToArray($dir) {
$result = array();
$cdir = scandir($dir);

foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value,array('.','..'))) {
        if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) {
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        } else {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
return $result;
} //Thanks to someone on this site for this function
```

I then take that array and pass it to another function to output it the way I need it to:

```
function OutputDirArray(&$arr, $x, $origName) {
$str;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($x == 0) $origName = $key;

    if (is_array($value)) {
        if($x > 0) $str .= '</div>';
        $str .= '<div class="infoDiv clearfix"><span class="title">'.$key.'</span><br/>'.OutputDirArray($value, ++$x, $origName).'</div>';
        --$x;
    } else {
        if($x > 0) {
            $str .= '<div class="displayImgs"><img src="images/'.$origName.'/'.$value.'"/></div>';
        } else {
            $str .= '<div class="infoDiv clearfix"><span class="title">Profile Picture</span>
                    <div class="displayImgs"><img src="images/'.$value.'"/></div></div>';
        }
    }
}
return $str;
```

}

My `var_dump($dir_array);` output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "img1.jpg" ["test1"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(15) "subimg1.gif" [1]=> string(9) "subimg2.png" [2]=> string(9) "subimg3.jpg" ["test3"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "subsubimg1.gif" [1]=> string(9) "subsubimg2.png" [2]=> string(9) "subsubimg3.jpg" } } ["test2"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "subimg1.gif" [1]=> string(9) "subimg2.png" [2]=> string(9) "subimg3.jpg" } }
```

What am I trying to do here is take in the dir_array and walk through outputting the html code. Everything seems to work fine except for two problems...

1) If I have a subsub directory, $key in `<span class="title">'.$key.'</span>` outputs the correct key (in my case, test3). However $origName in `<img src="images/'.$origName.'/'.$value.'"/>` outputs the original key used (test1).

2) I believe because of my subsub dir problem, I am left with an extra `</div>` after the subsub (test3) outputs.

It's been too long now trying to figure this out, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected output? Also, it's not clear how the recursion depth makes a difference.

Comment: My expected output is a div containing a span for the title(folder name) and each file in their own separate divs. I get exactly that except if there is a sub sub folder, in which I get an extra closing div.

Comment: Well, why are you outputting the closing `</div>`? You don't seem to leave a `<div>` opened anywhere; how about just remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very close to what you want

If you would like me to comment it I would gladly do so.

The code preview looks really nice.

Just a tip, get the html correct before you start to add attributes. It only makes things more complicated.

```
<?php
    function dirToArray($dir) {
        $result = array("name" => substr($dir, strrpos($dir, "\\") + 1), "children" => array());
        foreach(scandir($dir) as $key => $value) {
            if (!in_array($value,array('.', '..'))) {
                if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) {
                    $result["children"][] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
                } else {
                    $result["children"][]["name"] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function OutputDirArray($arr, $origName = ".", $tab = "") {
        $str = "$tab<div>$origName</div>";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($arr["children"]); $i++) {
            $child = $arr["children"][$i];          
            $name = $child["name"];         
            $path = $origName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;
            if ($child["children"]) {
                $str .= "\n$tab<div>\n" . OutputDirArray($child, $path, "$tab\t") . "\n$tab</div>";
            } else {
                $str .= "\n$tab<div><img src=\"images\\$path\"/></div>";
            }
        }
        return $str;
    }

    echo outputDirArray(dirToArray("path\\to\\file"), "path\\to\\file");
?>
```

Comment: Opps, I hit enter before I was done and took too long to edit... 1) I changed $path to `$path = substr($path, strpos($path, "\\"));`. 2) I left the first <div> open and close it when the if is true. And then took out the beginning and end div around the recursion. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you have this:

```
if($x == 0) $origName = $key;
```

I assume this only sets the original name to the key if you are at level zero, since `$x` is passed in. Since I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do here, I'm not sure what the solution should be, but my guess is that you should check the value of `$key` against the `$origName` passed in or something instead of `$x`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure now that I passed $x because I wanted to make $origName an array filled with all sub folder names but it turned out to take in the new key (default key numbers instead of test3).